# Is robots metatag mandatory or could I leave it like content=""?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I am using this tag like this on pages that I do not want to index, follow etc.:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet" />
```

I have also a robots.txt file in my root with something like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /account/
```

My question is if I am using this code as my robot meta tag:

```
<meta name="robots" content="" />
```

I mean there is nothing inside content variable. Is it html5 valid and OK from SEO point of view or not? If not what should I put inside the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look into [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/semantics.html#the-meta-element)

If either *name* or *http-equiv* is specified, then the *content* attribute must also be specified. Otherwise, it must be omitted.

If a *meta* element has a *name* attribute, it sets document metadata. Document metadata is expressed in terms of name/value pairs, the *name* attribute on the *meta* element giving the name, and the content attribute on the same element giving the value.

The name *robots* is not one of the standard metadata names (See [4.5.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/semantics.html#standard-metadata-names)), that means there is no restriction on their value and it can be empty.

Comment: Yes, you can even drop this tag.